# Advice needed: simple cross platform (OS-X and Windows) + SQLite development without installation

Tags: windows, macos, sqlite, cross-platform, development-environment

## Advice needed cross platform develop environment for OS-X and Windows + SQLite

I need a simple maintenance program to be run on but OS-X and Windows machines to update a SQLite database, one time.

## Use case:

Database maintenance on a SQLite database of an application on both OS-X and Windows.

## Requirements

- Simple GUI for file dialog to select the SQLite database and select a directory
- No installation of runtime environments.
- Same code for Windows and OS-X
- That's why I do not prefer Java, because on new versions of OS-X there is no Java installed
- Support for SQLite. Need to run several SQL scripts, based on some logic
- The user should only start and stop the application, select the a local SQLite database somewhere on his system and start the maintenance program = Scripts.
- (A database management tool is far to complicated for the users)
- Open source, freeware or to be used free commercially

It is a one time maintenance, so it should be as simple as possible

Which develop environment can I use best for this?

Comment: I'm not sure that such a thing meeting all your requirements exists.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use Tcl/Tk.

- [SQlite began as Tcl extension](http://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html)
- The SQlite extension is maintained by the SQlite authors.
- Tcl/Tk is available for many platforms.
- Tk is an old but still maintained, evolving Toolkit for GUIs.
- You can wrap your code in a [Starpack](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3663), a single executable that contains everything: The Tcl/Tk runtime, the SQlite extension, your scripts.
- Tcl/Tk are licensed under a BSD-Style license.

Here a sample script for the GUI.

```
package require Tk
package require sqlite3

ttk::label .lbldb -text "Database:"
ttk::entry .db -textvariable db
set db {}
ttk::button .seldb -command seldb -text "..."
grid .lbldb .db .seldb -sticky nesw -columnspan 2

ttk::label .lbldir -text "Directory:"
ttk::entry .dir -textvariable dir
set dir {}
ttk::button .seldir -command seldir -text "..."
grid .lbldir .dir .seldir -sticky nesw -columnspan 2

ttk::button .go -command go -text "Go!" -default active
ttk::button .exit -command exit -text "Exit"
grid .go .exit -sticky nesw -columnspan 3

grid columnconfigure . 2 -weight 1
grid columnconfigure . 3 -weight 1
grid rowconfigure . 2 -weight 1

proc seldb {} {
    set res [tk_getOpenFile -initialfile $::db]
    if {$res ne {}} {
        set ::db $res
    }
}

proc seldir {} {
    set res [tk_chooseDirectory -initialdir $::dir]
    if {$res ne {}} {
        set ::dir $res
    }
}

proc go {} {
    # Connect with the database
    sqlite3 db $::db
    # Do some stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xojo will do everything, you need. It can create standalone apps that do not require a runtime for Windows and OS X. It also has built-in support for SQLite.

It is free to use for development, but you'll need a license to create builds for deployment.

http://www.xojo.com